"Could not read source map for chrome-error..." when using Visual Studio Code to debug JavaScript in Edge
I am trying to debug javascript code in visual studio code but it gives me the following error
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/edge-elixir-neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"


the launch.json file has foll configurations
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       
        {
            "name": "Launch Edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "msedge",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        
    ]
}

I tried to delete .vscode folder alongwith launch.json file and next time when trying to add microsoft edge again nothing works. when starting again it show me this page Localhost refused to connect . I dont understand why its giving me chrome error when i am trying to use Edge for debugging.
I have,
Visual studio code: 1.90.2 version
Edge : Version 126.0.2592.68

Well, this error seems fairly esoteric to me, and may only apply to your specific situation/setup. However, if we try to use some context clues here, you're getting an HTTP error of 503. This code means a temporary downage for maintenance or something else of the like.
Can you try using a different browser and see what return value it gives you?

@Zenais When I change the port to 5500 which is the same port used by live server extension it shows me the page which has all the folders of the root folder. This folders have javascript files, when I navigate through this folders to open the file it opens up the application/index.html but still debugging is not running in VSCode

First I like to thank @Kendrick for guiding me in the right direction, I tried the things as he said and found out that the following launch.json file configuration works. The debugger can be launched for any subfolder javascript file for debugging.


{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:5500/${relativeFileDirname}",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}



Here the relativeFileDirname is the keyword that is important and this can be used for any browser configuration.

Please make sure http://localhost:8080 has some content and is accessible to you. You can either test:

Use another valid URL for "url" section to check if it is a problem from VS Code side.
Directly access http://localhost:8080 in your browser. If it is not accessible, it means you just used an invalid URL for "url" section.

For me, I can only reproduce this issue if I don't have anything on http://localhost:8080. Replacing it with another valid URL works.

When I change the port to 5500 which is the same port used by live server extension it shows me the page which has all the folders of the root folder. This folders have javascript files, when I navigate through this folders to open the file it opens up the application/index.html but still debugging is not running in VSCode

@Tushar Not quite sure what you mean by "navigate through this folders to open the file", but it looks like you need to change "launch" into "attach" if you open the file manually. "launch" only works if you start debugging (F5) inside VS Code. Anyway, the original problem can be solved by providing a valid URL.

I have root foldername as web development and some some subfolders within that, so the js or index.html file which are root folder runs in  VSCode debugger properly but those js/index.html files which are in subfolder does not run in debugger for e.g subfolder name is ToDo it has index.html, style.css and script.js files. script.js file is imported in index.html using 
@Tushar In this case, you need to specify the URL as http://localhost:5500/ToDo. Or simply move the index.html file right under http://localhost:5500.

Ok I got it working, but how should I modify the launch.json file that debugger works for root folder file and sub-folder files as well.

@Tushar In this case you may need to do "attach" instead of "launch". I'll suggest you take a tour around this documentation on debugging first: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

try to use real ip (not localhost\127.0.0.1) and project port
